# Can't upload file (random tmp path)

Tags: php, upload

I'm using lampp 7.2.5 & also tried on server with php 7.1. I'm trying to create a file hosting website but there is only 1 error. I couldn't find any solution for it so I'm asking for help now. I have a PHP code like this:

```
$ftp_server = xxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
$ftp_username = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
$ftp_userpass = xxxxxxxxx;
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$remote_file = "/uploaded/".$file_name;
if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII))
{
    echo "Successfully uploaded $file.";
}
else
{
    echo "Error uploading $file.";
}
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
```

And HTML:

```
<form action="sent.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" id="file" name="file" class="inputfile" onchange="danee()">
            <label for="file" class="chose" id="chose">Wybierz plik</label>
            <div id="info">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" onchange="checkEmail()" autocomplete="email" class="userdata" placeholder="E-mail"><Br/>
                <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" onchange="checkPass()" autocomplete="new-password" class="userdata" placeholder="Hasło do pliku"><Br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Wyślij" id="send">
            </div>
        </form>
```

And the problem is when I reload the browser and try to send any file, there shows that error:

> Warning: ftp_put(): Can't open that file: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/host/sent.php on line 10
>   Error uploading /opt/lampp/temp/phpgQoyn9.

And there always shows "/opt/lampp/temp/php[and some random characters]
Can someone help me? Pleaseee

Comment: You need to call [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) to move it somewhere accessible *first*. PHP prevents you from directly accessing freshly-uploaded files for security reasons.

Comment: Where is the "somehere accessible" place?

Answer (score 0):

You are upload image in directory. And then execute other process.

> move_uploaded_file($file, $remote_file)

```
if (move_uploaded_file($file, $remote_file) && ftp_put($ftp_conn, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII))
{
    echo "Successfully uploaded $file.";
}
else
{
    echo "Error uploading $file.";
}
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
```

Comment: That doesn't work :( Still getting error:   Warning: move_uploaded_file(/uploaded/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/host/sent.php on line 19

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/opt/lampp/temp/phpf4FEgr' to '/uploaded/index.php' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/host/sent.php on line 19
Error uploading /opt/lampp/temp/phpf4FEgr.